# PATCH when the resource location is not known

Tags: rest, api, http

I am building a rest API and want to implement a PATCH for a job manager monitoring tool.

All my clients know the job manager's job ID that is not unique. The job manager resets the jobs ID from time to time (so starting from 1 again) This happens at random intervals (can be months or days) for different reasons.

I want to let the job manager send me updates about a job but I don't want it to first do a GET to find out the job's unique ID (let's say DBid) and then do the PATCH /jobs/:DBid. This is because of performance and slow network reasons. Having to wait for the GET could block the job manager which is critical.

Selecting the latest job with the job manager ID will return the right job. But how to model this in a rest API?

Comment: If you don't know the manager ID, then what kind of information will the request be able to use to identify the correct job manager?

Comment: job name, day of submission and user could uniquely identify the right job. In 99% of cases day of submission is enough, other known fields could be added for certainty.

Comment: Then you have 2 options: 1. Create a URL structure that contains all those components, or 2. Don't use PATCH and use some custom POST rpc-like endpoint instead. It's not REST if you can't use urls to identify resources.

Answer (score 0):

You need the id of the job manager to be in a 'pot' on the server. I've worked on this type of thing where a client needs to know the internal id of a resource but that id rarely changes. It does change but very infrequently. The solution for that is a cache service but for this, it sounds like you need a 'pot', on the server, where the id is stored.

The endpoint handling the PATCH knows where the pot is on the server so can load the id from it. A simple flat file perhaps.

If the manager needs to change the id, whatever process handles that change, changes what's in the pot. So the PATCH endpoint is always getting the correct id from the pot.

You can add synchronisation for accessing the pot in case a PATCH comes in while the manager is updating the id.